# How to plot one DataFrame column against another one, each in its own subplot by a third column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I apologise in advance if it doesn't contain all of the information you need, the way you'd like it to be laid out (but please let me know).

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this (loosely based on a dataset that I am attempting to analyse!):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfdict = {'Person' : ['A','B','B','C','A','A','B','C','A'],
          'Year': np.random.randint(2006,2017,9), 
          'Score':np.random.randint(0,100,9)}

df = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)
```

What I would like to do is to plot a line chart of `Score` vs `Year`, for each `Person`, in their own subplots. I have tried by ordering the DataFrame first like so:

```
df.sort_values(['Person','Year']).plot(x = 'Year', y = 'Score')
```

What I get is a zig-zag line that does not look like a time series, in a single plot. What I would like to see is one subplot for `Person` A containing their `Score` vs `Year` in chronological order, one for B containing their `Score` vs `Year` and one for C containing their `Score` vs `Year`.

**Edit**: the groupby() solution by Quang Hoang works somewhat but does not generate the three subplots with different line colours and legend. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby().plot()`:

```
df.groupby('Person').plot(x='Year',y='Score')
```

Then you would get three plots, each for a person.

Comment: Thank you, that works, but each subplot now shows a line of the same blue color and "Score" in the legend, whereas I would like three different line colors and the legend to display A, B, C respectively.